# Unable to run query in Presto

Tags: presto

I am installing presto for first time. I created a single ubuntu instance in amazon ec2 and installed all the dependences required to install presto. I followed https://github.com/facebook/presto .

I did git clone and got the source code then I ran `$mvn clean install` as per instruction. Then I ran `$presto-cli/target/presto-cli-*-executable.jar`. while executing query it is showing an error as shown in image below

[image]

Please help me in solving this. The same I want to try in cluster containing master and slaves.

Answer (score 0):

while working with ec2 make sure that you have your own AMI, Keypair and security group.

Comment: I launched ubuntu ec2 instance using the AMI given by amazon. I have the keypair and security group also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your server is not running or is hosted on another port number.
Have you started the server using

```
./presto-server-x.x/bin/launcher.py start
```